# JS Error: main.js:93 Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm receiving this error on my main.js:

```
main.js:93 Uncaught ReferenceError: review is not defined
at showFullReviewBody (main.js:93)
at HTMLSpanElement.onclick ((index):1)
```

That error I cannot explain because the code was working and I even remember that I change something. So Iùm stuck with it.

My full code involved in this and the error is in the bottom part last 2 functions:

```
// THE REVIEWS DATA
getReviews(processReviews);
// tell js where is the widget
var widget = $('#widget');
function processReviews(reviews) {
// total number of reviewers
var total = reviews.length;
// initialize reviewSum variable to add all review ratings in it
var reviewSum = 0;
var carousalHtml = '';
// loop through each review
$(reviews).each(function (index, value) {
// add current review's rating in global reviewSum variable
reviewSum = reviewSum + parseInt(value.starRating);
// review Body if text is bigger then 200 characters then add more 
functionality
var reviewBody = value.reviewBody.length > 180 ? value.reviewBody.substr(0, 180) + '... <span class="showFullReview" onclick="javascript: showFullReviewBody($(this) ,' + index + ');">more</span>' : value.reviewBody;
// create class for Bad, Middle and good review for styling purposes
var reviewStarsClass = '';
var reviewSmile = '';
if (parseInt(value.starRating) > 2 && parseInt(value.starRating) <= 3) {
  reviewStarsClass = 'middle';
} else if (parseInt(value.starRating) >= 0 && parseInt(value.starRating) <= 2) {
  reviewStarsClass = 'bad';
} else {
  reviewStarsClass = 'good';
}
// Create HTML for carousal
carousalHtml += `
    <div class="testimonial">
      <div class="top">
        <span class="name">` + value.fullName + `</span>
        <div class="star-rating ` + reviewStarsClass + `">
                <span style="width:` + 20 * parseInt(value.starRating) + '%' + '" id="starRatingPresenter"><strong>' + value.starRating + `</strong> out of 5</span>
             </div>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <span class="firstQuote fa fa-quote-left"></span>
        <span class="main">
        ` + reviewBody + `
        </span>
        <span class="lastQuote fa fa-quote-right"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
      ` + value.location + `
      </div>
    </div>
      `;
    });
  // calculate average rating
  var averageRating = reviewSum / total;
  // Calculate happiness percentage
  var averageRatePercentage = 20 * averageRating;
 // calculate average rating's class for styling purposes
 var reviewStarsClass = '';
if (parseInt(averageRating) > 2 && parseInt(averageRating) <= 3) {
reviewStarsClass = 'middle';
} else if (parseInt(averageRating) >= 0 && parseInt(averageRating) <= 2) {
reviewStarsClass = 'bad';
} else {
reviewStarsClass = 'good';
}
// Set dynamic text for banner
var bannerText = '';
var reviewSmile = '';
if (reviewStarsClass == 'good') {
bannerText = 'We\'ve got our customers happy !';
reviewSmile = '<i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
} else if (reviewStarsClass == 'middle') {
bannerText = 'Sometimes we\'re unable to fullfil needs of our customers';
reviewSmile = '<i class="fa fa-meh-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
} else {
bannerText = 'Customers blame us for everything';
reviewSmile = '<i class="fa fa-frown-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>';
}
// Create HTML for widget
var html = `
   <div class="half first">
      <span class="widgetTitle ` + reviewStarsClass + `">
        ` + reviewSmile + `
        <h3>` + bannerText + `</h3>
      </span>
      <div class="averageRatingInfo">
         <div class="star-rating ` + reviewStarsClass + `">
            <span style="width:` + averageRatePercentage + '%' + '" id="starRatingPresenter"><strong>' + averageRating + `</strong> out of 5</span>
         </div><br>
         <div class="averageRatingWrap">
            <span class="averageRating">` + averageRating + ` <span class="light">Rating</span></span>
         </div>
         <div class="reviewersWrap">
            <span class="reviewers">` + total + ` <span class="light">Reviewers</span></span>
         </div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
         <hr />
         <div class="reviewFooterIndicator">
            <span class="fa fa-star ` + reviewStarsClass + `"></span> Reviews
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="half second">
        <div class="owl-carousel testimonials">` + carousalHtml + `</div>
   </div>
      `;
   // Apply widget html
   widget.html(html);
   // Initialize Carousel
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
   loop: true,
   margin: 20,
   autoplay: true,
   autoplayTimeout: 6000,
   nav: true,
   navText: [
  '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
  '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
  ],
  autoplayHoverPause: true,
  responsive: {
  0: {
    items: 1
  },
  480: {
    items: 1
  },
  600: {
    items: 2
  },
  1000: {
    items: 2
  }
  }
  });
  }

  // Function to show all review text when clicked on more button
  function showFullReviewBody(e, id) {
  console.log(id);
  var contentPlace = e.closest('span.main');
  var fullText = review[id].reviewBody + ' <span class=\'showFullReview\' 
  onclick=\'javascript: showLessReviewBody($(this),' + id + 
 ');\'\'>less</span>';
 contentPlace.html(fullText);
 }

function showLessReviewBody(e, id) {
console.log(id);
var contentPlace = e.closest('span.main');
var reviewBody = reviews[id].reviewBody.substr(0, 180) + '... <span 
class="showFullReview" onclick="javascript: showFullReviewBody($(this) ,' + id + ');">more</span>';
contentPlace.html(reviewBody);
 }
 // Function to get reviews - to see a banner effect change based on the 
 average of the reviews change the reviews .json file
 function getReviews(reviews) {
 $.ajax({
 url: 'API/reviews.json'
 //url: 'API/goodreviews.json'
 //url: 'API/badreviews.json'
 }).done(reviews);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I look into your `showFullReviewBody` function. You are calling `review[id]`. I think you mean to call `reviews[id]`

Answer (score 0):

"var reviewBody = reviews[id].reviewBody.substr(0, 180) + '... more';
contentPlace.html(reviewBody);"

review is not defined due to reviews variable not defined under function. so please defined global array and push all values then use.